# Flag row has duplicate value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query problem. I have 3 table.

```
table A 
    ----------------------------
    NAME   | CODE 
    ----------------------------
    bob    | PL
    david  | AA
    susan  | PL
    joe    | AB
    alfred | PL



table B 
    ----------------------------
    CODE | DESCRIPTION
    ----------------------------
    PL   | code 1
    PB   | code 2 
    PC   | code 3

table C 
    ----------------------------
    CODE | DESCRIPTION
    ----------------------------
    AA   | code 4
    AB   | code 5 
    AC   | code 6
```

Table B and C have unique row.
the result I need to flag which row has duplicate records:

```
    -------------------------------------
    NAME   | CODE | DESCRIPTION | DUPLICATE
    -------------------------------------
    bob    | PL   | code 1      | YES
    david  | AA   | code 4      | NO
    susan  | PL   | code 1      | YES
    joe    | AB   | code 5      | NO
    Alfred | PL   | code 1      | YES
```

What I have tried so far

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffb2eb/16

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle is in MySQL, not Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need tables `B` and `C` at all to calculate the flag.  You can do this with window functions:

```
select a.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by a.code) > 1 then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flag
from a;
```

You do need `B` and `C` if you want to bring in the additional values:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.description, c.description) as description,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by a.code) > 1 then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flag
from a left join
     b
     on a.code = b.code left join
     c
     on a.code = c.code;
```

Here is a working **Oracle** [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c6df/2).

Comment: @muhnizar - **YOU**, not Gordon, tagged the original question as `Oracle`, not `MySQL`. (Or, possibly, the StackOverflow website tagged it for you automatically, but you didn't correct it before posting your question.) ALWAYS pay close attention to the tags at the bottom of the post. Even after the fact (like, **right now**) you can `edit` your post and **change** the tags to reflect the database you are using.

Comment: @gordonlinoff - if tables B and C are as shown, and assuming they are disjoint (as they should be, otherwise the problem doesn't quite make sense), it may be more efficient to UNION ALL between B and C and join the result to the "big" table - so there is only one join instead of two.

Comment: @mathguy I did wanna ask in oracle but I showed the wrong fiddle(mysql).
Now I am curious what syntax 
"(case when count(*) over (partition by a.cod) > 1 then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end)" for mysql??

Comment: @muhnizar - OK - the reason I wrote what I wrote is that the ONLY comment to Gordon was about MySQL. I don't see your earlier comment starting with "Thank you Gordon, this works fine in Oracle, which is what I needed, but I would like to see how it works in MySQL also." The **only** thing you said is "I guess it doesn't work with MySQL." I don't see you having marked the answer as Correct, as it should be if your question was really about Oracle.

Comment: @muhnizar . . . I included the SQL Fiddle that does work with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code in MYSQL (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a149b/1)

Note :- The code works in Oracle as well http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c6df/5

```
select A.*, 
COALESCE(B.DESCRIPTION, C.DESCRIPTION) AS DESCRIPTION,
 dup.DUPLICATE
 from A 
left join B on A.CODE = B.CODE
left join C on A.CODE = C.CODE
INNER JOIN (select a.code,
        case when count(a.code) > 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as 
        DUPLICATE 
        from A 
        group by a.code) dup
        ON A.code=dup.code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think by using UNION would be need more "memory" than not using it (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: you can tune the query using the syntax having count(code) for MYSQL and avoiding union which i will try

Comment: i have updated the answer without using union and just using case to update duplicates

Comment: @muhnizar did u try my solution in MYSQL??